# How to send custom parameters for a GET method in Alamofire?

Tags: swift3, alamofire

I've this `array = [1,2,3]` and I want to send it like this:

`http://somedomain.com/today?intersets=1,2,3`

I'm trying to send it like this:

`let params: Parameters = [ "intersets": array]`

`Alamofire.request(url, method: .get, parameters: params ,headers: header)`

but after printing `response.request`, I got this:

`http://somedomain.com/today?intersets%5B%5D=1&intersets%5B%5D=2intersets%5B%5D=3`

Any ideas on how to fix this request?

Comment: Note that *if* your server is actually expecting an array and parsing the commas again then using your current approach is actually more correct since that is how you transmit an array via GET.

Comment: @luk2302 Thanks man, out of the question, you mentioned this is the way in GET, so does it change in POST ?

Comment: In the POST body you mostly send json which has native support for arrays and therefore do not need any string manipulation. What I meant to say previously was "in the URL parameters" which is the only place to put parameters in GET.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should join the array into a `String` and send that as the parameter.

```
let string = array.joined(separator: ",")
let params: Parameters = [ "intersets": string]
```

Comment: I got this `blahblahblah/today?intersets=1%2C2%2C3`,
how to remove %2C from and replace it with `,`

Comment: You can't send a `,` directly as a parameter, as in a URL, you should **encode** special characters. `%2C` is the encoded form of `,`.